# php file wont run properly on my server that I just set up via Cyberduck

Tags: php, apache, localhost, vagrant, localserver

I've set up a local server with Vagrant via Cyberduck on my Mac. There seems to be no problem with running a file in general (I guess?) except for php file for some reason. It simply shows what I typed in, which is

```
<?php
echo "hello from Vagrant";
```

instead of saying `hello from Vagrant`
I also did `sudo vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf` and see what seems to be the problem that's causing this.

```
# PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language which attempts to make it
# easy for developers to write dynamically generated webpages.
#
<IfModule prefork.c>
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
</IfModule>

<IfModule !prefork.c>
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5-zts.so
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .user.ini files from being viewed by Web clients.
#
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy All
</IfModule>
</Files>

#
# Allow php to handle Multiviews
#
AddType text/html .php

#
# Add index.php to the list of files that will be served as directory
# indexes.
#
DirectoryIndex index.php

# mod_php options
<IfModule  mod_php5.c>
#
# Cause the PHP interpreter to handle files with a .php extension.
#
<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

#
# Uncomment the following lines to allow PHP to pretty-print .phps
# files as PHP source code:
#
#<FilesMatch \.php$>
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
#</FilesMatch>
```

Also here's some quick info about my software version that I've used so far.
PHP 5.6.15
Apache 2.2.15
CentOS 6.7
Cyberduck 4.7.3

Anyone knows any solution to this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: stupid but is `libphp5.so` correctly installed with user right ? do you have any error in apache/access log ?

Comment: i havent had any errors so far. any ways to check them both? srry im really new to this.

Comment: go to your `/etc/httpd/logs/` folder and check for `access_log` and `error_log` see if something pops up for the php script file